# $digest error on $watch for changes in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application receive updates on items via SSE (server sent events) from the API.

What I have is a main controller that looks for this changes:

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('/items/updates');
} else {
  console.log('SSE not supported');
}

source.addEventListener('items', function (e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
  Items.updateOneItem(data);
  $scope.$digest();
}, false);
```

**Items** is a service factory that handle the changes:

```
App.factory('Items', function () {

    var items = {};
    // previous and updated item
    var previousItemState = null;
    var updatedItem = null;

    items.list = [];

    items.getUpdatedItem = function () {
        return {
            previous: previousItemState,
            updated: updatedItem
        };
    };

    items.updateOneItem = function (item) {
        var i = $.map(items.list, function (e, i) {
            if (e !== null) {
                if (e.id === item.id) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        });
        previousItemState = items.list[i];
        items.list[i] = item;
        updatedItem = item;
    };

    return items;

});
```

Basically in this service I store the items and I'm trying to check if an item has been updated and what exactly is changed in the item model.

In my controller I'm watching this and doing my controls, or maybe I'm trying to do that:

```
$scope.$watch(Items.getUpdatedItem, function (item) {
    if (item.previous !== null && item.updated !== null) {
        // do my controls on previous and updated item...
    }
});
```

What happen is that I have an error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! [...]
```

I tried, from my Items service, to return just a single value and it works fine but I receive just the updated item and I don't know how to check in what the item is changed:

```
items.getUpdatedItem = function () {
    return updatedItem;
};
```

My questions are:

- Why I can not return an object from my service method?
- What is in this case the best practice to have the previous and updated item in order to see changes?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are not supposed to run `$digest()` manually. Wrap the code you need to digest in [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Second thing, it is correct to pass your object like this:

```
items.getUpdatedItem = function () {
    return updatedItem;
};
```

Problem you are having with accessing old and new version in `$watch` is easily solved. Second parameter you are passing to `$watch` is a function that actually use [two arguments](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

```
$scope.$watch(Items.getUpdatedItem, function (newItem, oldItem) {
    if (oldItem !== newItem) {
        // do my controls on previous and updated item...
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice to know about the `$timeout` resolving the SSE updates. I used your code and it worked fine after having added a second parameter `true` to the `$watch`, otherwise `oldItem` was returning `null`. Thanks for your help mate.